# dc.js geoChoroplethChart width smaller than 500 crops the map

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, choropleth

This is the code I used for drawing USA map

```
<div class="row">
    <div id='map' class="span12"></div>
</div>

window.map = dc.geoChoroplethChart('#map');
d3.json('us_states.json', function (statesJson) {
    map.height(500)
    .dimension(Proper_Dimension_No_bug_here_well_tested)
    .group(Proper_Group_No_bug_here_well_tested)
    .colors(from colorbrew)
    .colorDomain(derived from data)
    .colorAccessor(function (d) {
         return d;
    })
    .projection(d3.geo.albersUsa())
    .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", function (d) {
         return d.properties.name;
     });
     dc.renderAll();
});
```

How can I make this map smaller? For example, Height 250 Weight 480. Changing the height property in `geoChoroplethChart` object does not make the map small, rather crops it. I also failed trying fixing height of the `map` div via inline CSS. The following image is the cropped map where height is set to 300.
[image]

Comment: See the documentation for [d3.geo.projection](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Projections.md) and modify the protection parameter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to scale down each state not just change the height/width of the chart. So try this:

```
map.selectAll('g.state').each(function (d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(0.5)')
})
```

EDIT:

Here is an example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kzqkvpwa/

[image]